# Chrome HTML5 canvas scaling

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

From what I heard on S.O. and elsewhere, the `ImageSmoothingEnabled` option of the canvas context has been enabled in Chrome since v22.0. I can't seem to get chrome to respect this, or any other of the methods here on stackoverflow for getting a pixelated image with Chrome (version 23.0). No matter what  I try for css or in the javascript, the image is still interpolated when drawn in Chrome. For instance, I've tried

```
image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             // Older versions of FF
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          // FF 6.0+
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; // Webkit
image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         // Possible future browsers.
-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   // IE
```

and

```
var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
context.ImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

These settings do work with Firefox however. Does anyone know how to force chrome to pixelate a canvas image these days?

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me (Chrome 24.0.1312.56, Windows 7):

```
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: weird, I'll try it again. I think I was on a slightly older version of chrome.